# Why does Excel Table Format, always use absolute referencing in formulas. Any way to disable it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The Table format (Home> Format As Table) option is a good feature of Excel. I am using it in Excel 2013.

But when I put a formula and try to copy it across, it does not work. Trouble comes when you want to repeat different sets of formulas etc.

Does anybody know a solution to this. I know that by dragging the formula, it works, but when you have thousands of rows, its terrible to drag.

Edit 1: Putting manual referencing also works, but its cumbersome, and we don't use excel for doing it manually.

Edit 2: A sample file uploaded. [Link](http://www.filedropper.com/superuser_1). In the file I have data in Table format. I put a Subtotal formula in B1, and copied it to C1 and D1. The references do not change in C1 and D1.

Comment: This question is impossible to even speculate on without sample data and sample formula(s) together with expected results.

Comment: Expected result is simple, when u copy a formula, the reference should change automatically, as is the simple way excel works..

Comment: If you put a *Total Row* to use, there should be no problem. If you are not using a *Total Row* then some sample data with the formula located appropriately would shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Am not using a Total Row. Sample file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The *structured references* you are trying to use are treated like *named references* when used outside of the actual table. That is to say, using `Table1[USA Sales]` rather than `B$3:B$6` is like defining B$3:B$6 using Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name manager; there is an underlying cell reference but it is locked. Conversely, the `Table1` area can be used like a defined name are sliced off with `INDEX`.

[image: Structured References in Tables]

The formula in D2 is,

`=SUBTOTAL(9,INDEX(Table1, , COLUMN(B:B)))`

Fill right as necessary. That formula will dynamically grow with the addition of new rows to Table1.

Using a **Total Row** does not require this `INDEX` slicing as the total row is a part of Table1. Filling right in a total row would adjust to the column above the new formula much as relative cell references do. You are running into difficulties because you are using the structured references from outside the table.

[Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)